# C# Aggregation on custom objects

Tags: c#, aggregation

I have a `List<Fields>` collection where the class Fields has the following properties

`(Name, Currency, Amount, Date, OtherList)` where OtherList is a List

**Sample values**

```
Name  Currency  Amount Date         F1    F2    F3  
ABC   XX        12     12 Jan 2013  X     Y     Z  
BCA   YY        11     12 Jan 2013  A     B     C  
ABC   XX        10     13 Jan 2013  X     Y     Z
```

Now OtherList object will have the values `(X, Y, Z)` for `record1` and `(A, B, C)` for `record2` et.el

What I need to do is apply an aggregation on the above list on the fields Name, Currency, F1, F2 and F3 so that the result is as follows.

**Output**

```
Name  Currency  Amount Date         F1    F2    F3  
ABC   XX        22     13 Jan 2013  X     Y     Z  
BCA   YY        11     12 Jan 2013  A     B     C
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var aggrList = list
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Currency, x.F1, x.F2, x.F3 })
    .Select(grp => new {
            Name = grp.First().Name,
            Currency = grp.First().Currency,
            Amount = grp.Sum(x=>x.Amount),
            Date = grp.Max(x=>x.Date),
            F1 = grp.First().F1,    
            F2 = grp.First().F2,    
            F3 = grp.First().F3,    
        });
```

Comment: I'm sorry but otherList is not a List<string> but Dictionary<string, string>. I need to group based on the values in the Dictionary. Also, the above solution does not seem to work because I can use only x.Name, x.Currency and x.OtherList and not x.F1, x.F2 in the GroupBy clause.

Comment: The reason being x.OtherList is the exposed property and not x.F1 et el

Answer (score 0):

Try to group this way:

```
list.Where(x => x.OtherList != null && x.OtherList.Count >= 3 )
    .GroupBy(x => new {F1 = x.OtherList[0], F2 = x.OtherList[1], F3 = x.OtherList[2]})
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.First().Name,
        Currency = g.First().Currency,
        Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount),
        Date = g.Max(x => x.Date),
        F1 = g.Key.F1,
        F2 = g.Key.F2,
        F3 = g.Key.F3,
    });
```

I guess for `Date` you will apply `Max()` function, for Amount - `Sum()`, but how you plan to apply aggregation for `Name` and `Currency` fields?